# Cross account AWS RDS access from AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-aurora

I have two AWS accounts (**A** and **B**). I need my AWS Lambda function in account A to access the Aurora RDS in account B.

How can we achieve this?

Is there any IAM role that I need to configure in both AWS accounts?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68384069/13126651

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connecting AWS Lambda and RDS in different AWS Accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68384069/connecting-aws-lambda-and-rds-in-different-aws-accounts)